# Can I offer an optional free trial for iOS auto-renewal subscriptions?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, subscription

For example, I have one account for my app and two app store accounts.

can use the free trial for two month with both App Store accounts. 
(If you have more accounts, you will be able to use more periods than examples)
Is this just a problem with SandBox?

If not Is there a way to store this on my server and then branch it?

If the value of `is_using_free_trial` stored in my app is false, I want to be able to use the free trial, and when it is true, I would like to make the payment immediately without the free trial.

Can this be done in the App Store?
I implement it via `ReactNative` and I couldn't find any relevant options at `react-native-iap`

Comment: You can use the device check API to limit it to one trial per device.

Comment: @Paulw11 
There is a Check API, but how can I limit the trial after checking?
The App Store always launches a trial if your account changes.

Comment: You would need to have two subscriptions in the same subscription group. One with the free trial and one without. You then show the appropriate product for purchase based on eligibility. Honestly though you may find that very few people would go to the trouble of setting up new accounts just to get free trials.